# Java server wait for all clients to be ready

Tags: java, tcp, server, client, multiplayer

I'm currently making a little multiplayer game with Java. Two clients connect to the server. When they are connected, in each round, they send a number to the server. They can do it simultaneously. I'm using threads to handle the socket's incoming data. If all the two clients have sent their number, the server sends data to the clients.

Currently, I'm doing this with a single while loop, something like this in pseudocode:

```
while(!readyForEvaluate){
      readyForEvaluate = allClientSentData();
}
```

Where allClientData() returns a boolean, which checks logical variables, if player 1 and 2 have sent their number.

Basically, this solution is working for me, but my question is: Is there a more efficient way of solving this kind of problem, or what is the general solution?

Comment: You should handle user inputs as "Events", and run check / send data on them. That will reduce the useful duty cycles